# What functions a lexer needs to provide?

Tags: javascript, lexical-analysis

I am making a lexer, don't tell me to not do because I already did most of it.
Currently it makes an array of tokens and that's it.

I would like to know, what functions the lexer needs to provide and a brief explanation of what each function needs to do.

I'll accept the most complete list.

An example function would be:

**next**: Consume the current token and return it

Also, should the lexer have the `expect` function or should the interpreter implement it?

By the way, the lexer constructor accepts a string as argument and make the lexical analyses and store all the tokens in the "tokens" variable.

The language is javascript, so I can't overload operators.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to compile a comprehensive list by writing a program that uses your lexer, and implementing the functions you end up needing.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, you need:

- `nextToken` — move forward in the input and get the next token.
- `curToken` — return the current token; don't move
- `curValue` — tokens like STRING and NUMBER have values; tokens like SEMICOLON don't
- `sourcePos` — return the source position (line number, character position) of the first character of the current token

*edit* — oh also:

- `prefetch` — initialize the lexer by getting the first token.

Additionally, for some languages you might want 2 or more tokens of lookahead. Then you'd want a variation on plain `curToken` so that you can look at a bigger "window" on the token stream. For most languages that's not really necessary however.

*edit again* — also I won't tell you not to write one because they're basically the funnest things ever. In javascript you can't get too crazy, but in a language like Erlang you can have your lexer act like a "token pump" by making it generate a stream of tokens it sends to a separate parser process.

Comment: I mostly agree with your sample functions, except these two: 1. "tokens like STRING and NUMBER have values; tokens like SEMICOLON don't": True, but I don't think this is the lexer's job to figure out these values. Especially in a statically-typed language where you cannot return different types of `value` from the `Token` object. I'd rather say it's a job of semantic analyzer which works on top of Parser and Lexer (value=semantics), or Parser's job if it needs to convert the token into a literal constant node in the AST. Thought I can see some benefit of it: avoiding scanning the lexeme twice.

Comment: 2. `prefetch`: Should this function throw an error when there's nothing in the input buffer to prefetch? If yes, then what if the empty source is a valid program? Prefetching would cause an error. I think it's better to return an error when `nextToken` fails to get anything more from the input buffer, since it is an error when the parser expects some more text and there is none (premature end of file), similarly to `expect` mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Think a second time about what you're asking: "what functions the lexer needs to provide"

What it it "needs" depends of course on what **you** need, not what **it** needs. We will probably be able to give you better aid if you explain your own needs. But well, here's a shot anyway:

A minimal one would consist of a single function that takes a string as an argument and returns a list of strings (or an iterator over strings if you want to be fancy and deferred). That's enough for many use-cases and hence is what a lexer "needs".

A more descriptive one could return more complex objects than strings, containing further information about each token (such as it's position in the original string for example, so that you'll be able to tell the poor programmer with syntax errors in his code where he should look). You can probably come up with lots of meta data to add in there besides line numbers, but once again, it all depends on your needs.

Comment: But this is a valid question to ask, if one wants to design an *interface* for his lexer in a way to make it ready for different user needs and make it comfortable to use it. There are some common use cases for a lexer, and missing them in one's design could be bad. Think of it as a question about a usual "design pattern" for a lexer.